# How to disable a submit button until user refreshes the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a multi-step form and my form is divided in three pieces, so all and good.

I want that if the user clicks on the final submit button after validation in JavaScript and PHP the user get redirected to my desired page but the submit button must be disabled if he clicks on the back button the button must be unclickable until he refreshes the complete form.

Form code:

```
<form id="newlogo" class="sky-form" name="newlogo" method="post" action="action.php"> 
/* reandom inputs */
```

Final submit button:

```
<button type="submit" name="form_btn" id="sub" class="button" onclick="return logotype() ,logotype()">Submit</button>
```

I just need to disable this button if it past the validation codes and enable it only by refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies and keep a state enable/disable for the button

Comment: how to do that for example i'm not very familiar with php overall thanks

Comment: You can use jQuery to work with cookies: $.cookie('name', 'value'); to set a value and $.cookie('name'); to get the value